# How is request (socket connections) bean scoping handled in absence of http requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scoping

I'm building a back-end service which needs to handle 100,000 requests per day (mvp) and up to 1 million thereafter.

Our requests are not HTTP requests (due to high demand) so a request is received in industry standard format (assume fixed length text file) which is converted to a java object and that object is later written to socket which my app will receive.

Traditionally I would have assumed that all beans should be request scoped since that is essentially what I want, but since requests are not HTTP I'm very confused about how to scope this correctly. Each socket transmission should get its own set of beans and it should not interfere with the previous or following transmission.

Could you kindly help point me in the right direction? Http and request aware annotations (@RequestScope) seem to not apply in my case but yet that's very close to what I want to achieve. Likewise I'm unable to meaningfully research since I am unsure what vocabulary to use. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How about introducing your own scope as described http://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-scope You can use ThreadLocal storage to keep the beans or even use the thread scope https://memorynotfound.com/spring-custom-scope-creating-and-implementing-threadscope/

Comment: @StanislavL thanks for the suggestions.  I'll give that a shot.  I was also trying to gauge the validity of my assumptions to determine if I was just going about it all wrong.  I'll update this with my findings.  Many thanks.

Comment: @StanislavL, thanks again for the suggestions. After much research I went with InheritableThreadLocal in conjunction with a ConcurrentHashMap. It seems to be exactly what I needed.

If you want to make yours an official answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about introducing your own scope as described [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-scope). You can use ThreadLocal storage to keep the beans or even use the thread scope [See here](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-custom-scope-creating-and-implementing-threadscope/)